# Is there a simple way to remember the current user's language?

Tags: django

I've a multilanguage website. It's easy to change the language, Django handle this perfectly. The problem is with batches. The [documentation is perfectly clear about this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). But I need to send mail = batch = command line about "what's new for the website".

So:

1. I need to know the language of the current user
2. I need to switch to this language.

The 2nd point is solved in the documentation. The problem is #1. I'm wondering if there's something I missed about multilanguage and if Django *does* remember for the current user his/her language, of if we have to do it on our own. If so, could you put me on track to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Save it in your DB when user register on your site.

Comment: @Gocht The user can change his language after registration, at any time. This is not a valid solution.

Comment: You can create no editable fields in your models.

Comment: @Gocht I need to know the user's choice because of batches that are ran at 2am. See my own answer, and thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution: make a middleware that checks the current language of the website, and the user's language in the database. If they're different, remember the language in the database. FYI I have my own model `Langue` which contains informations about a specific language, including `locale` which is the two letter local (e.g. `en`, `fr`, ...)

```
class CheckIfLanguageChangedMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware to check if language has changed. 
    Used for remembering the user's choice for batchs files:
    batchs files can't guess each user's language.
    Adds a bit overhead but can't avoid that (I guess).
    """
    @staticmethod
    def process_request(request):
        try:
            p = Personne.objects.get(user__pk=request.user.pk)
            langue = translation.get_language()
            if not p.site_language or p.site_language.locale != langue:
                try:
                    p.site_language = Langue.objects.get(locale__exact=langue)
                    p.save()
                except Langue.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
        except Personne.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```